# Save DataGridView to clipboard formatting > CSV C# .Net

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview, clipboard

I am using the following to save a DataGridView to a CSV File. However when i open the file after it has completed its copy, it has commas at the start of the entry. Here is a direct cut and paste of the output format:

the line spacing is zero, i just couldant put them on their own lines for some reason

,Item,ItemDescription,CurrentCount,OnOrder

,1,Chicken food,5,No

,2,Dog food,2,No

I want it to look like this;

1,Chicken food,5,No

also the last line of the file looks like this;
,,,,

here is the code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count == 0) {
        MessageBox.Show("You have not loaded the Stock
        Inventory","Error"); }
    else
    {
        IDataObject objectSave =
        Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        dataGridView1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText;
        dataGridView1.SelectAll();
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataGridView1.GetClipboardContent());
        File.WriteAllText("C:\\Stock\\Stock.csv",

        Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.CommaSeparatedValue));
        MessageBox.Show("Save Complete","Sucess!");
    }
}
```

Comment: There are libraries to read and write CSVs very reliably

Comment: @WelcomeOverflow In fact, the .Net framework contains a native csv parser, though they hid it away in the VisualBasic namespace for some odd reason. It's called `TextFieldParser`.

Comment: I am very well aware of `TextFieldParser`: it is  pale and crude compared to things like CSVHelper.  All it does is chop the data into a string array.  Better libs will parse it into DTos @Nyerguds